# Wave optics, intensity distribution

Tags: optics, waves, interference, intensity

Do Gaussian beams have a gaussian intensity distribution? If so, why?

Does the intensity distribution depend on the profile of the light beam?

Answer (score 0):

> Do Gaussian beams have a gaussian intensity distribution?

Yes, in the transverse direction. The full functional form is given in Wikipedia.

> If so, why?

By definition. If they didn't have a gaussian intensity distribution, we wouldn't call them gaussian.

The more interesting fact is that there exist solutions to the wave equation (in the paraxial approximation) with a gaussian profile in the first place. This is not guaranteed *a priori*, though asking "why?" isn't a particularly answerable question. It's partly due to the fact that the wave equation in the paraxial approximation is a relatively simple differential equation, which limits its solutions to a relatively limited class of functions. But from a certain point it just boils down to "because that is one solution to the equation".

> Does the intensity distribution depend on the profile of the light beam?

The intensity distribution *is* the profile of the light beam. This question makes no sense.

Comment: Intensity is the square (or magnitude) of the E field and the beam profile was derived with this equation in mind as well as other relationships.

Comment: I think you can refer to either the intensity distribution or the complex E-field distribution as the "profile"? It's not well defined